# Perl write String from XML to File using difficult Regex

Tags: regex, perl

i am having a XML file which i need to transfer to a list with Perl (without using XSLT).

This is my (simplyfied, removed like 10 more attributes to make it easier to read!) XML:

```
...
<XMLTAG ID="1" name="NAME1" status="0" date1="24.05.2012 13:37:00" date2="25.05.2012 13:37:00" />
<XMLTAG ID="2" name="NAME2" status="1" date1="24.05.2012 13:37:00" date2="25.05.2012 13:37:00" />
<XMLTAG ID="3" name="NAME3" status="0" date1="24.05.2012 13:37:00" date2="25.05.2012 13:37:00" />
...
```

What i got so far:

```
my $input = in.xml;
my $output = out.txt;

# open input
open( INPUT, $input )
  || die "Can't find $input: $_";

# open output
open( OUTPUT, ">$output" )
  || die "Can't find $output: $_";

    # run until perl returns undef (at the end of the file)
    while (<INPUT>) {
        if ($_ == /date1=\"[0-3]?[0-9].[0-3]?[0-9].(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2} [0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\"/) {
        print OUTPUT $_;};
    }
    close(INPUT);
    close(OUTPUT);
```

The output file should look like this:

```
date1="24.05.2012 13:37:00"
date1="24.05.2012 13:37:01"
date1="24.05.2012 13:37:02"
...
```

Thanks in advance,
Marley

Comment: let me give you a code, there is a good usage of regex match by name at line 45. You should definitely match by name for better readability: https://github.com/seckin206/Log2KML-Parser/blob/master/logviewer.pl

Comment: **if( m#date1="([^"]+)# ) { print "date1=$1" ; }**

Comment: Never parse XML/HTML/CSV files using regex. Use the existing modules, they are usually mature, stable and well tested.

Comment: If all pleas to use an XML parser are going to fall on deaf ears, then I suggest `/(date1="[^"]+")/ and print "$1\n"`

Comment: @Borodin there is also performance comparison for similar regexes of your and my solution to this problem. Maybe curious ones can benefit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215669/regex-comparison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'in.xml');
printf qq(date1="%s"\n), $_->getAttribute('date1')
    for $dom->findnodes('//XMLTAG');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a proper XML parsing module. There are many available, but here is a solution using [`XML::Smart`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSmart).

It's not a solution I would choose, but I would be interested to know why you have written off XSLT?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Smart;

my $input = 'in.xml';
my $output = 'out.txt';

open my $out, '>', $output or die qq(Can't open output file "$output": $!);

my $xml = XML::Smart->new($input);
my $text = $xml->{root}{XMLTAG};

my $xmltags = $xml->{root}{XMLTAG};

for my $tag (@$xmltags) {
  print $out qq(date1="$tag->{date1}"\n);
}
```

**output**

```
date1="24.05.2012 13:37:00"
date1="24.05.2012 13:37:00"
date1="24.05.2012 13:37:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open in.xml ;
ls //@date1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
date1=\"(.*?)\"
```

for your regex, it will make a non greedy search.

UPDATE:

they warn me that there is no need for escaping double quotes, so

```
date1="(.*?)"
```

will do.

Comment: There is no need to escape the double-quotes.

Comment: I don't have a perl interpreter right here, so I can't verify your comment, my friend.

Comment: I can verify that double-quotes don't have special meaning in regex, so unless you match with `m"some-regex"` there's no need to escape.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a non-greedy match, like this:

```
if ($_ =~ /(date1=".*?")/ ) {
       print OUTPUT "$1\n";
    }
```